# Excel VBA Code Save and Close

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through 2000 csv files, convert them to xls, make changes to the spreadsheet.

I can't work out how to save and close the workbook before moving on to the next.

I tried the following at the end of the script.

```
Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I get a Minor loss of fidelity message.

The full code

```
Sub batchconvertcsvxls()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strFile As String, strDir As String, strOut_Dir As String, myNewFileName As String

strDir = "C:\csv\" 'location of csv files
strOut_Dir = "C:\converted\" 'location of xls files
strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.csv")

Do While strFile <> ""

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=strDir & strFile, Local:=True)

    With wb
        .SaveAs strOut_Dir & Replace(wb.Name, ".csv", ".xls"), 56
        .Close True
    End With
Set wb = Nothing

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=strOut_Dir & Replace(strFile, ".csv", ".xls"))

Rows("1:1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.RowHeight = 60
Selection.ColumnWidth = 30
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Columns("E:E").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("E2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    DataFound = False
    j = 2
    While DataFound = False And j <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(j, i).Value <> "" Then
            DataFound = True
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    If DataFound = False Then
        Columns(i).Hidden = True
    End If
Next

strFile = Dir

Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True ActiveWorkbook.Close
SaveChanges:=False

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure but if you want to save the changes shouldn't then this `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` be set to `True`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `wb.Close SaveChanges:=False` since you have set the workbook as `wb` that may get it to close without the message box popping up.

Also you can try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`(this goes at the start of your code), it stops most types of messages popping up (there are some errors that cannot be stopped though(I dont have a list to hand but "out of memory" is an error that cannot be prevented for instance)).

I'll look into it a bit more sine im doing this off the top of my head and update the post if I get any more